# Excel 429 Run-time Error from VB application CreateObject("Excel.Sheet") - Work as User but don't as Admin on windows 10

Tags: excel, vb.net, windows-10

here is my problem :

What I Saw :

My old appli always worked before win10 but can't launch Excel anymore when execute as admin on win10.

What I tried :

I suspected a problem with rights in administrators / users so I dug and noticed "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" folder.

So, I changed right to give full control to administrators on this folder and children.

Still no change.

So, I expect a problem of link in registery but can't find any clue in this.

What de you think about it ?

Does registeries are different in admin / user mode ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `WindowsApps` has nothing to do with desktop apps which Excel is, and by messing with its permissions you have compromised your system. In any case I don't see why you would want to have `CreateObject("Excel.Sheet")`, because that confusingly yields an instance of `Workbook`, and there are better ways to create workbooks.

Comment: Well, to be specific, this appli do lot of things and the only part failing is this one which try to open datas (dump) in excel.

Comment: I highly doubt this is anything to do with user privileges. What is actually happening? Do you get an error message? [ask]

Comment: My Error is : Run-time error 429: ActiveX component can't create object.


What is happening is : 
Launch appli as user => can launch Excel with data on sheet.


Launch appli as Admin => Run time error 429: ActiveX component can't create object.


Maybe this is only a side effect ? But can't guess how this is possible...

Comment: Have you launched Excel manually as admin?

Comment: Yes, I can launch Excel manually as admin and as users, both worked.

Comment: Well, we found a workaround : re install Office 365.
Can't explain exactly why this error occure but reinstallation fixed it.
(Maybe pre-installed version fault...)
In any case, thank you for your support !

Answer (score 0):

Well, we found a workaround : re install Office 365. Can't explain exactly why this error occure but reinstallation fixed it.

(Maybe pre-installed version fault...) In any case, thank you for your support !